# No setter/field for Social_Security_Number found on class

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

I am getting this warning and then a subsequent NullpointerException.

After looking through articles some more, I tried making sure my Java Class names matched the ones in my Firebase DB, but I am still getting the error.

FirebaseDB:
[image: Unverified Employee]

Warning/Error:

```
01-03 13:03:01.963 23252-23252/? I/FirebaseMethods: checkIfUsernameExists: checking if imail@address.com already exists.
01-03 13:03:01.965 23252-23252/? I/FirebaseMethods: checkIfUsernameExists: datasnapshot: DataSnapshot { key = RC9zIioE6vc5vlhrIethmbqyFDS2, value = {Social_Security_Number=5555, Email_Address=imail@address.com} }
01-03 13:03:01.981 23252-23252/? W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Social_Security_Number found on class com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Models.EmployeeUser
01-03 13:03:01.981 23252-23252/? W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Email_Address found on class com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Models.EmployeeUser
01-03 13:03:01.981 23252-23252/? I/FirebaseMethods: checkIfUsernameExists: email: null
01-03 13:03:01.987 23252-23252/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                          at com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Adapters.FirebaseMethods.checkIfUsernameExists(FirebaseMethods.java:46)
                                                          at com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Activities.RegisterEmployeeActivity$1$1.onDataChange(RegisterEmployeeActivity.java:122)
```

FirebaseMethods.java:

```
public boolean checkIfUsernameExists(String emailAddress, DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
        Log.i(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: checking if " + emailAddress + " already exists.");

        EmployeeUser user = new EmployeeUser();

        for (DataSnapshot ds: datasnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.i(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: datasnapshot: " + ds);

            user.setEmailAddress(ds.getValue(EmployeeUser.class).getEmailAddress());
            Log.i(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: email: " + user.getEmailAddress());

            if(user.getEmailAddress().equals(emailAddress)){
                Log.i(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: FOUND A MATCH: " + user.getEmailAddress());
                return true;
            }
```

EmployeeUser.java:

```
public class EmployeeUser {

    private String user_id;
    private String Email_Address;
    private String Social_Security_Number;

    public EmployeeUser(String user_id, String Email_Address, String Social_Security_Number) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.Email_Address = Email_Address;
        this.Social_Security_Number = Social_Security_Number;
    }

    public EmployeeUser(String Email_Address) {
        this.Email_Address = Email_Address;
    }

    public EmployeeUser() {}

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return Email_Address;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.Email_Address = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return Social_Security_Number;
    }

    public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String socialSecurityNumber) {
        this.Social_Security_Number = socialSecurityNumber;
    }

}
```

RegisterEmployeeActivity.java:

```
 mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                //1st check: Make sure the username is not already in use
                                Log.i("DATA VALUE", dataSnapshot.child("RC9zIioE6vc5vlhrIethmbqyFDS2").getValue().toString());

                                if (firebaseMethods.checkIfUsernameExists(email, dataSnapshot)) {
                                    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailET.getText().toString(), passwordET.getText().toString())
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterEmployeeActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
```

Comment: You don't plan on storing that SSN in plain text do you?

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point. I was just trying to get one part working and move onto that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[Java Naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)**, your model class should look like this:

```
public class EmployeeUser {
    private String userId;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String socialSecurityNumber;

    public EmployeeUser(String userId, String emailAddress, String socialSecurityNumber) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public EmployeeUser(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public EmployeeUser() {}

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String socialSecurityNumber) {
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    }
}
```

You are getting `No setter/field for Social_Security_Number found on class` error because Firebase is looking for a field named `socialSecurityNumber` accordingly to your `getSocialSecurityNumber()` getter method. Your field is `Social_Security_Number` instead of `socialSecurityNumber` and therefore that error.

Comment: Thanks. I started out with it like this, but I thought it would look nicer in Firebase with capitals. I guess I got in my own way. Best to keep it simple. Lesson learned.